# Linking to Gurobi c++ from rcpp

Tags: c++, r, makefile, rcpp, gurobi

I would like to use to the gurobi c++ interface in a rcpp package.

I understand that I have to adapt the Makevars.win files for this. I managed to include the header file. However, the compiler (I tried gcc and clang++) complains about undefined references such as

```
undefined reference to `GRBEnv::GRBEnv(bool)
```

which suggests that I did not succeed in adding the necessary linking directives in Makevars.win. In my makefile, I have

```
PKG_LIBS += -L"$(GUROBI_HOME)/bin${R_ARCH}"-gurobi91.dll
```

since it's recommended to use the bin folder rather than the lib folder in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars). But a solution with the lib folder would also help me.

I might be linking to the wrong files since the gurobi [documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/quickstart_mac/cpp_building_and_running_t.html) says that it is necessary to link to `libgurobi_c++.a` and `libgurobi91.dylib`. But I cannot find these files on my computer: I have `gurobi91.lib` in lib (together with a host of other files such as `gurobi_c++md2019.lib`). I tried unsuccessfully with these two and also with  `gurobi91.dll` from bin.

It could also be the that I have to do something in the `DESCRIPTION` file of my package, but the `LinkingTo` option seems to be to include headers which I can (seemingly) do successfully.

Any help or hint to any documentation is appreciated :)

**EDIT**

Thanks to @zkoza, it turns out that I have to link to the C++ library gurobi_c++mt2015.lib and C library gurobi91.lib . Now my question is how to do that. I've looked through the [list](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) of R packages which import RCPP (reverse imports). Not many packages seem to have a Makevars.win file. Some have configure files, others makefiles, others Cmakelists. Among those that do have Makevars.win files, most are the basic ones from the `Rcpp` `skeleton`. But I found the `RcppMeCab` package which has a customized Makevars.win [file](https://github.com/junhewk/RcppMeCab/blob/master/src/Makevars.win) with `PKG_LIBS` that I tried to emulate by setting

```
PKG_LIBS += -L "$(GUROBI_HOME)/lib" - gurobi91.lib - gurobi_c++mt2015.lib
```

leading to the errors

```
g++.exe: error: gurobi91.lib: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: gurobi_c++mt2015.lib: No such file or directory
```

which is are at least very transparent. Could someone please point me to a documentation/example of how to use `PKG_LIBS`, `LDFLAGS` or any other flags I have to set here? The syntax is nebulous to me.

For completeness, I do not want to call gurobi's c++ API from R, I just want to be able to call it from my C++ files.

Comment: You seem to be using windows makefile, but following documentation for Mac OS (`quickstart-mac`).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This falls under the topic of 'how do I build an R (or Rcpp) package with external libraries" which complicated.  I answered many prior versions of this here which you can search by adding `[rcpp] library` to the search bar (plus maybe additional terms).  I also wrote an entire paper on this that is incldued as a vignette with your Rcpp package.  In short it is _hard_ as we have no means to ensure _users_ will have gurobi at all, or the required version, if any.

Comment: FYI: `libxxx.a` is a static library for POSIX systems, such as GNU/Linux.  `libxxx.dylib` is a static library for MacOS systems.  `xxx.lib` is a static library for Windows systems.  Be sure you're following the correct directions for the type of operating system you have.

Comment: @zkoza: Thank you for making me aware that I was reading the gurobi documentation for the wrong platform. Switching to the [windows doc](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/quickstart_windows/cpp_building_and_running_t.html), I have learned that I need to include the C++ library gurobi_c++mt2015.lib and C library gurobi91.lib. That's already extremely helpful, now I only have to figure out how to do that :)

Comment: Thank you, @MadScientist, that is helpful!

Comment: Thank you, @DirkEddelbuettel. I see that it is hard and read your 13 steps paper and looked at it's 5000 line configure [file](https://github.com/corels/rcppcorels/blob/master/configure). My hope is this case should not be as hard since I do not attempt to call the C++ library from R. I just want to call it from C++ and then call my own C++ functions from R via the `Rcpp` interface. For the moment, I'd be more than happy if I was able to compile the package on my own machine and then worry about portability and checking requirements.

Comment: Yep, local builds are a first step.  Distribution is a different ballgane.  BTW "I just want to call it from C++ and then call my own C++ functions from R via the `Rcpp` interface." is still the same thing as you _want to extend R with compiled code having a dependency on an external library_.  It is lovely that we can do that but as you see deployment can be challenging.  But congrats on having some _working_.  That matters most at the initial stages, and may even be good enough,  It all depends.

Comment: I wish I had something working ':D I still have to figure out the syntax of this Makevars.win file to actually make it work on my machine. But I already measure the difficulty of the problem of distribution that will come afterwards...